# Indent Javascript lambdas with clang-format

Tags: clang-format

I have two test files:

test1.js

```
fetchData().then((data)=>{
    console.log('fetched', data);
});
```

test2.js

```
fetchData().then((data)=>{
    console.log('fetched', data);
}).then(()=>{
    console.log('finished');
});
```

I run clang-format on them as follows:

```
clang-format-5.0 -style="{ColumnLimit: 0}" testX.js
```

Formatted test1.js

```
fetchData().then((data) => {
  console.log('fetched', data);
});
```

Formatted test2.js

```
fetchData().then((data) => {
             console.log('fetched', data);
           })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('finished');
    });
```

(clang-format-3.8 produces the same output)

What style options (in addition to column limit 0) would format test2.js as follows?

```
fetchData().then((data) => {
  console.log('fetched', data);
}).then(() => {
  console.log('finished');
});
```

In other words, I want the presence or absence of the 2nd lambda not to affect the formatting of the 1st lambda.